# Perl push values into Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have created a simple multi-dimensional array:

```
my @arraytest = ([1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]);
print "Array - @$_\n" for @arraytest;
```

Output:

```
Array - 1 2 3 
Array - 4 5 6 
Array - 7 8 9
```

How do I push "10, 11, 12" to the next element in this array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an array reference, and push that as the next element. The easiest way is to make an anonymous array ref.

```
push @arraytest, [10, 11, 12];
```

Your output now looks like this:

```
Array - 1 2 3
Array - 4 5 6
Array - 7 8 9
Array - 10 11 12
```

The important part is that your `@arraytest` is an actual array (not a reference), so you can just operate on it directly with `push`, `pop` and so on.

See [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) for more details.

Comment: The question could also read as _push that string_, then the answer would be `push @arraytest, "10, 11, 12";`.